# Set cwd in VS CODE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, path

VS CODE 1.52.1
Python 3.7.9

Path structure

- MyWorkspace

  - Folder Main

    - MyWorkspace.code-workspace
    - MainModule.py
  - Folder A

    - SubModule_A.py
  - Folder B

    - SubModule_B.py

---

In the past, I could import "MainModule.py" in all of sub-modules in any directory easily like below.

```
import MainModule
```

But after I reinstall VS Code, they are unable to find modules in different paths. I've found some solutions importing modules with absolute paths, but there are hundreds sub-modules already making hard to modify them all.

I tried below but nothing works.

1. Modifying cwd

In "SubModule_a.py",

```
import os
os.chdir("C:\\work\\Folder Main")
import MainModule
```

This still arises ModuleNotFoundError

2. Modifying "MyWorkspace.code-workspace"

   "settings": {

   ```
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\anaconda3\\envs\\MyEnv\\python.exe", # for virtual env
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "terminal.integrated.cwd": "C:\\work\\Folder Main" # added this line
   ```

   }

In short, how can I import "MainModule.py" from "SubModule_A.py" without using absolute path?

Answer (score 4):

To import the module successfully, there're two optional ways:

1.Add the following code in launch.json:

```
"env": {
    "PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceFolder}"
},
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

Then run it through **Run without Debugging(Ctrl+F5)**. It will still throw error if you run by clicking the green triangle button in the upper right corner.

[image]

2.Append the current path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./')
from FolderMain import MainModule
```

When we import a module, python interpreter will search in the current directory, installed built_in modules and third-party modules, the search path is stored in `sys.path`. `./` represents the current path.

[image]

This works both, whatever you run it without debugging or in Terminal.

Comment: My problem is solve with your 1st option. However, 'Unable to import 'MainModule'' message is still linted and module names are not guided. Do you have any idea to solve that as well?

Comment: can you post the error screenshot? cause different linter has different settings to solve it